# java swing- Possible to add JLabel next to application icon/title?

Tags: java, string, swing, title, jlabel

Is the above question possible? The effect I'm trying to achieve is similar to how MS Word displays "Document- Microsoft Word (Technical Preview)" in this picture link: http://img.blogsolute.com/ms-word-2010.png, but with a colored background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the title of any frame you create by passing the title string to the constructor of the JFrame. You can't, however, add any controls to the 'decoration' portion of the frame - i.e., the title bar.

What you probably *can* do, however, is create an undecorated frame, and manually add the decoration using customised Border objects. This effectively allows you to put any controls you like around the outside, and the root pane will happily work inside it.

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to achieve. Anywhere I can find a tutorial?

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: Look for the setUndecorated() method of JFrame in the help docs, and then check out the Border interface for known classes that implement borders and the setBorder() method. The documentation is at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need `JLabel` for that? You can use `setTitle("")` for this purpose